# How to create an Entity Data Model in .net framework console app with oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a .NetFramework 4.6.1 console application on my Visual studio 15.9.21 and added the following packages via nugget manager:
-EntityFramework v6.0.0
-Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v19.9.0
-Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramwork v19.7.0

When I tried to add the project ADO.NET Entity Data Model I selected EF Designer from data. Since there was nothing in the drop down for the connection, I made my own connection where I choose the ODP.NET, Mangaged driver and entered the necessarry parameters in the EZ connect option.
After I got the message that there is a successfull connection I pressed ok and from then on I got the follwing error:
`Object referene not set to an instance of an object`.

I cant even save the connection in the appconfig because the Entity Data Model Wizzard is not allowing me to continue.

The database Im trying to connect to is Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.

The weirdest part is that if I open the server explorer I can see the connection I just created and can easily see all the tables and data there.

Here is my generated app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.19.1"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
      connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;Password=oracle_user_password;Data Source=oracle"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I create my Entity Data Model for this particular connection?

Comment: Is the query return results?  You may have a good connection but just not getting any data back.  Remove any WHERE from query and see if you get data.

Comment: @jdweng Yup, I have results when I open the table from server explorer.

Comment: But what about in c#?

Comment: @jdweng That as well, I just tested it using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand to execute a simple query

Comment: What line of code is failing? Looks like you are getting good data and then getting the exception.

Comment: @jdweng The code is not failing at all. Its the Entity Data Model wizzard that is failing on me, i cannot finish it to create my entety model

Comment: Did you try following : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsForVisualStudio2019

Comment: I remember to always have problems with edmx+Oracle. This doesn't really help with your question, but if you have any chance to chose your toolbox, I recommend to go with code first from database instead of model first. You will have to overcome some problems anyway, but from my experience, configuration and ongoing development with code first is better documented and supported than model first.

Comment: @jdweng that looks like its for VS19, im using VS17

grek40 I know, and Im using code first for a different project, but in this particular one I dont have that freedom so I must use model first.

Comment: Then why are you using : Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramwork v19.7.0